# drupal 7: trying to make use of Compressing JS and CSS causes Major Error

Tags: performance

hi I want to enable the compression of my JS and CSS to speed up my drupal site, but when I tick these boxes my site breaks completely. I can't even reload the performance page to remove the tick!! Thankfully I leanred this sometime back so I open the perf page twice tick on one and apply, see error then save the other loaded page which resets the situation.

error message for either CSS or JS tick is

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

Also I CAN set these ticks on my localhost verion of the site, I get this problem on the hosted site.

anyone know why I can't use these features?

edit. Also there is nothing in the logs when I get back into the site.

error below was shown when warnings and error were turned on to display

```
Error
Error message
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'WATCHDOG_ERR' for column 'severity' at row 1: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => The specified file %file could not be copied to %destination. [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => a:2:{s:5:"%file";s:22:"temporary://fileFTC3lH";s:12:"%destination";s:64:"public://css/css_jZfSPTZv1KVtNJ48SyQgcHuPQjmI4wt9aqGhI5N-Vyg.css";} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => WATCHDOG_ERR [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => http://www.martynazoltaszek.com/admin/config/development/performance [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => http://www.martynazoltaszek.com/admin/config/development/performance [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 87.74.16.7 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1334073447 ) in dblog_watchdog() (line 157 of /home/martynaz/public_html/modules/dblog/dblog.module).
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an error with the file-system? Go to admin/config/media/file-system, check the settings or just hit the save button again. But backup your site befor you do this. Have you tried to upload a file? Do you get any other cache / temp error? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: hi the filesystem appears to be in good working order, after uploading I alterd the c:\temp to sites/default/files/tmp and this made uploading work without error. at the moment uploading to the site is fine. however I did try your suggestion of hitting Save, but it makes no differnce. Also I cleared the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Something is really odd with your symptoms.  If you look at the code for [`_drupal_log_error`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21errors.inc/function/_drupal_log_error/7), you will see that there is a `watchdog()` that logs a PHP error in the dblog.  So, you really should be seeing something there.  You should also be seeing some other messages that pinpoint the exact location of the error.

Are you actually getting a maintenance page?  If you look at the code (which is the only source of that string), it should be appearing in one.

This are all shots in the dark, but ...

Make sure your messages are enabled, and make sure dblog is enabled.  Make sure you have nothing major (ie, red) on your status report page.

Make the error happen and then manually look at the `{watchdog}` table and look for the error.  I would also check the Apache `error_log`.  One of these two really should have the error message in it.

Comment: thanks for the info. I cannot see any red in the status, but I did turn on MEssages in dev loggin and errors, when I turn on CSS now I get a huge message dump. I've edit the post and included this. not sure what dblog is though? or how to manually look at watchdog or apache?

Comment: The error message says that something bad happened trying to log the error message.  Something is seriously wrong.

Comment: yeah I can see something is seriously wrong :) it appears to point to the temp directory location, but i've tried resetting this and get same error. I've had problems with the temp file location before on this site too...

Comment: The problem is bigger than that.  I think it implies that WATCHDOG_ERR is not defined properly as a constant.  I don't know how this is possible.

Comment: oh I see, awesome. do you find it odd that my local version is fine though? is it not likely the watchdog error is a symptom of the problem?

Comment: No clue anymore, but weird PHP problems like this can be caused by APC misbehaving.  Try disabling that.  After that, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the Database Logging or dblog module, compare these two things on your local and remote database installs:

- database user permissions for the site's database (can it create, modify tables, etc on both installs?)
- watchdog table's create statement, something like `show create table watchdog` ought to work on MySQL

Once you have this fixed, post the errors you see in the watchdog logs.